# What's the difference between itinerary and segment?

Tags: terminology, iata

I know that a segment is defined as the full flight from the airport where passenger A initially  boarded on the airplane to his/her last destination. A segment could be composed of multiple legs. However I don't understand what's the difference between a segment and an itinerary?

Comment: Hi and welcome. This [answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/84254/14897) should address all those terms.

Comment: An itinerary often contains multiple segments. Consider a round-trip booking.